# How can I add a custom coded side bar to my wordpress page?

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar, custom-widgets

I have a wordpress site , I would like to add a sidebar I created to my page on the right side of my content. I want it to appear on the top right side of my wordpress content and position exactly where my content starts.

I want it to appear as if I was using a regular WordPress widget. But I want it done manually.

** I am not trying to edit the theme , I am inserting this code into a template that is a plugin .The plugin I am using is running a job board on my site.... This plugin also came with built in pages, using WordPress sidebars makes the widgets appear on all pages

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I want this sidebar to be placed on a certain template file that I have .... and I only want it on the template ... I dont need answers involving sidebar.php files or wordpress widgets. I want to insert this on a template of my choice

Comment: Depending on where you want your code to appear, you might have to open sidebar.php, if your theme already has a sidebar. Else, take a look at [the list of templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) and decide on which one you would want to edit and include your custom sidebar.

Comment: It almost seems like you don't understand the hierarchy of the WordPress template directory. WordPress uses [get] functions to "call" certain template files, like [sidebar.php] to add this into the file. Could you possibly edit your question to include code of a file you want to add the sidebar to, such as your [single.php] file.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not a widget, you could manually add it by editing the theme's `sidebar.php` or one of the other template files (single.php, page.php, etc.). Your choice would depend on where exactly you want the result of your code to display.

Comment: The code comes from a plugin and I want to enter it on a template file ... Not in the theme sidebar file... I need it on a template

Comment: The sidebar file is a template file, just like single.php or index.php. If the plugin specifies that you add the code where you want the sidebar to be displayed, you would have to open one of these template files in the wordpress text editor and add it there. All these files are found in the active theme's folder under wp-themes